# How do I switch from UTF-8 char * to a dynamic encoding with Win32 API?

Tags: winapi, encoding, character-encoding, hunspell

I'm currently working on a project that uses Hunspell inside Node. The goal is a cross-platform spell-checking that works with encoding properly (`node-spellchecker`).

I have to use arbitrary dictionaries which have different encodings. Most have `SET UTF-8` in the `*.aff` file but other dictionaries have encodings like `SET ISO8859-1`. I get UTF-8 from Node but I need to convert it into the encoding for the dictionary. Then, I need to convert it in the reverse to handle suggestions.

With Linux, I can use `iconv` to convert it but I don't have that on the Windows side of things.  However, I'd like not to require UTF-8 dictionaries (that works).

Any suggestion or hints of where to start would be greatly appreciated. `WideCharToMultiByte` is used in one step, but I couldn't find a `MultiByteToMultiByte` that I would expect.

**Things I Have**

```
const char *from_encoding_name = "UTF-8"; // This can be swapped
const char *to_encoding_name = "ISO8859-1"; // This can be swapped
const char *word = /* möchtzn encoded in UTF-8 */;
```

**Things I Want**

```
const char *dictionaryWord = /* möchtzn encoded in ISO-8859-1 */;
```

Thank you.

Comment: Why not using MultiByteToWideChar to convert from utf-8, then WideCharToMultiByte to convert to the encoding you want?

Comment: `MultiByteToMultiByte` is a useless function if one of the code pages isn't UTF-8 as all other transforms are lossy. I can't imagine anyone thought it was a good idea to implement a function when pretty much anything it enabled would actually damage data.

Comment: @Chris that is not the fault of the function itself. Just because most ANSI charsets support only the small subset of the full Unicode repertoire, and converting between charsets *may* be lossy, does not mean such a function is useless, it just means you have to be careful with it, and accept that not all data will convert without loss.  For instance, converting from UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1 is perfectly fine as long as the UTF-8 data uses only codepoints that ISO-8859-1 supports.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that analog `MultiByteToMultiByte` exists in `WinAPI`. I'd use two calls: `MultiByteToWideChar` and then `WideCharToMultiByte`.

BTW, I looked into sources of .Net method [Encoding.Convert](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/text/encoding.cs) and there is also conversion is done through `UTF-16`.

Answer (score 1):

FYI, `iconv.exe` is available for Windows, you just have to install it manually.  Or you can embed `libiconv` directly in your project.

That being said, what you are asking for can be done using Microsoft APIs:

1. the Win32 [`MultiByteToWideChar()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/stringapiset/nf-stringapiset-multibytetowidechar) and [`WideCharToMultiByte()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/stringapiset/nf-stringapiset-widechartomultibyte) functions.  First decode the UTF-8 input to UTF-16 using `MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8)`, and then encode the UTF-16 to ISO-8859-1 using `WideCharToMultiByte(28591)` (or whatever target codepage you need).  And then just swap the codepages when going back the other way.
2. the [`IMultiLanguage::ConvertString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa741008(v%3dvs.85)) method, or the [`IMultiLanguage::CreateConvertCharset()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa741012(v%3dvs.85)) and [`IMLangConvertCharset::DoConversion()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa741052(v%3dvs.85)) methods.  These can convert input from one codepage directly to another.

You can use any of these to implement your own `MultiByteToMultiByte()` wrapper function.